# htmlspecialchars() throwing an error

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, elgg

I have installed elgg and none of the links work.  In the error log, I see a slew of these error messages:

> htmlspecialchars() expects at most 3 parameters, 4 given

Comment: Doesn't  the error message already tell you what is wrong?

Comment: Yes, but is this a known issue in ELGG?  I did not modify any of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need PHP 5.2.3 or later. That's when the 4th parameter to `htmlspecialchars` was added.

5.2.3 was released over 5 years ago!! So how old is your PHP version???

The current old version is 5.3.16 and 5.4.6 is the version you should really use.